# Why does text input in form fields become disabled when I switch from a web browser to another window and then back again?

Tags: html, windows, forms, input, text

I have a web application that uses a lot of text input. In some cases it's form input and a Submit / POST action and in others the input text is processed using JavaScript / Ajax.

If I begin typing into, for example, a textarea and then switch to another window (e.g. Outlook) to copy some content to the clipboard, and then switch back to the browser to paste it, the textarea no longer accepts keyboard input.

This only appears to happen on my Windows 10 Pro laptop. On Mac OS it works fine.
I've used multiple browsers.

Is there something in the Windows setup that disables form input as a security measure?

Here is an example of a form declaration in the markup:

`<form method="post" action="<?php echo __SITE_URL; ?>admin/_editcandidate.php" autocomplete="off">`

I don't use any JavaScript events that are triggered when the focus changes.

Appreciate any insights.

Comment: After switching back to the browser, is the textarea still in focus?

Comment: Hi Neil. Yeah it is. I've actually just solved my problem. I had a rogue 'KeyUp' event handler that I hadn't clocked. Typical!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this adds any value to anyone other than it's worth double checking your code for rogue event handlers.

I found this buried in an included file:

`window.addEventListener('keyup', function(evt) { keyboardUp(evt); }, false);`

and the associated function had a scenario where it could return false:

```
    function keyboardUp(e)
    {
        var key;
        if (window.event) // IE
        {
            key = e.keyCode;
        }
        else if(e.which)
        {
            key = e.which;
        }
        if (key === 18 && g.altkey === false) { g.altkey = true; return; }
        if (g.altkey === false) return;
        ...
    }
```

Pretty sloppy on my part.
Not sure why this should be an issue switching focus but it does at least solve my problem.